# VPN web traffic?

Tags: windows-7, vpn

Laptop is company issued. PC is personal. VPN only connected via laptop.

If I RDP to my company laptop on my home network is there any way the company could see any web traffic on my personal device?

Answer (score 1):

No, they can't look to see what you're doing on your personal computer over a RDP connection. Now, if you have it set up to share anything from your personal computer through RDP to the laptop (files for example), that will be a different story.